# Is dojo/on expected to be used when capturing events for DataGrid, with Dojo 1.7 and the AMD loader?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I'm converting a Dojo 1.6.1 DataGrid example to use the AMD loader in Dojo 1.7, and try and do things the "1.7 way".

Currently, I have `dojo.connect(grid, "onApplyEdit", applyEdit);` but I'd like to convert this to use dojo/on.

I thought a simple conversion to `on(grid, "onApplyEdit", applyEdit);` might work, but it does not.

I've noticed for some of the on() examples, the event names are regular dom events, like click.

Have the event names for the grid changed, or is dojo/on just not ready to handle non-DOM events, or perhaps the DataGrid has not been updated to emit on() events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dojo.on` works with DOM- and browser-related events. Non-DOM and non-browser events are simple method calls. You can connect to them using AOP. See `dojo/aspect.js` for more details: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/aspect

Comment: In the case of above example, would I be using aspect.after(grid, "doApplyEdit", applyEdit), since that is the "do" method that appears on the grid?

Comment: Yeah, why not. Because pseudo events usually do not have a body, you can use any AOP method you like. If you want chain handlers in FIFO fashion, like `dojo.connect` does, "after" is your ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it working this way:

```
var signal = dojo.on( grid4, 'ApplyCellEdit', function(inValue, inRowNdx, inStoreNdx){..});
```

Leave out the 'on' from the eventname 'onApplyCellEdit'.